# Hi, I am truing create SQl table and I am keeping getting this error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE DEAD( 
DEATH_ID INTEGER(10) NOT NULL,
DEATHYEAR INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KRY(DEATH_ID)
)
Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: PRIMARY K**E**Y

Comment: @jarlh: perhaps OP meant "primal scream" - which is still not valid SQL, but never mind. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, `integer` does not take a length.  `number` does, so:

```
CREATE TABLE DEAD ( 
    DEATH_ID NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    DEATHYEAR INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5eff8bc6fc158f1754ada825210e9a8c) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that I replaced the separate primary key constraint with an in-line constraint.  `NOT NULL` is redundant on a `PRIMARY KEY.